# How to Deserialise JSON Data to Array of Model objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have a C#/ASP.Net project using WebAPI2 that has an API endpoint.  That endpoint provides an array of JSON objects as a response to a GET request.  I use a Model of the native object for serialisation, which is the standard way in WebAPI2 as I understand it.

The serialization happens 'behind the scenes' when I send an OK HttpActionResult typed for an IEnumerable of models,

```
 return Ok<IEnumerable<Model>>(arrayOfModels);
```

I have a second app that receives the JSON string representation of the array of models.  The inbound string to deserialise looks like this, for an array with a single element...

```
[
  {
    "ExecID": "EXWB4KT-1",
    "Symbol": "CERT-EUR-TEST",
    "ExecutionTime": "2016-07-28T14:59:56.24",
    "BuyExchID": "IDH64KT-1",
    "SellExchID": "IDH64KT-3",
    "Tradable": {
        "CERT": {
            "AccSrc": "ANDY-CERT",
            "AccDst": "HIBLET-CERT",
            "Qty": "0.01000000",
            "State": "PENDING"
        },
        "EUR1": {
            "AccSrc": "HIBLET-EUR",
            "AccDst": "ANDY-EUR",
            "Qty": "0.33",
            "State": "PENDING"
        }
    }
  }
]
```

How should I rehydrate the JSON data, bearing in mind that I have the WebAPI2 model available in another project?

As I have control of both ends, I am thinking the deserialisation back into an array of models should be trivial, but I am not sure how to do it.  I know there are lots of possible ways to do this, I am looking for the sanest or cleanest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Newsoft.Json nuget package.  Then it's a matter of creating your model and deserializing.  Something like this:

```
public class MyObject
{ 
    int ExecID { get; set; }
    string Symbol { get; set; }
    //etc etc   
}
```

Then in your method:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MyMethod(string json)
{
     List<MyObject> objList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(json);
}
```

This code may not be exact, but should be something similar

Comment: Hot diggety, that's exactly what I was hoping for.  For others that come this way, the code exactly is 'List<Model> models = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(json);'